# ImageNet vs CIFAR pre-trained models for biomedical image classification

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification, transfer-learning

I'm doing research on transfer learning for biomedical image classification, mainly skin lesion classification. From what I know, both CIFAR and ImageNet are pre-trained on natural images and not biomedical images. However, which approach would be more ideal for analyzing dermoscopic images?

*I apologize if its a naive question*

Comment: You can refer to this Google AI [blog](https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/12/understanding-transfer-learning-for.html). Also [this](https://theaisummer.com/medical-imaging-transfer-learning/) might help.